# How to handle select event on autocomplete combobox

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a jquery ui autocomplete combobox for which I want to handle the select event. I found this answer on Stack Overflow: [Hooking event handlers to jQuery Autocomplete Combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705680/hooking-event-handlers-to-jquery-autocomplete-combobox)

But this solution does not seem to work for me. I have added the below to the original code for combobox but nothing is displayed on the console when I change selection:

```
$( "#combobox" ).combobox({
         selected: function(event, ui) {
           console.log("Selected");
            // Event handling code goes here.
         } // selected
      });
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yuLjat7g/5/)

What is the best way I to handle the combobox select event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On examining the combobox code you can see there's a trigger of a "select" event and not a "selected" event. I have no idea where this name "selected" came from in the above referenced post. I am using JQuery UI 1.12. So code should have been as follows:

```
$( "#combobox" ).combobox({
         select: function(event, ui) {
           console.log("Selected");
            // Event handling code goes here.
         } // selected
      });
```

[Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yuLjat7g/6/)